# Renaming executable's image name is giving it write permission

Tags: rename, permission-denied, createfile

Dear community members,

We have three of same hardware Windows 7 Professional computers. No one of them is connected to a domain or directory service etc.

We run same executable image on all three computers. **In one of them**, I had to rename it. Because, with my application's original filename, it has no write access to it's working directory.

I setup full access permisions to USER group in working directory manually but this did not solve.

I suspect some kind of deny mechanism in Windows based on executable's name.
I searched the registry for executable's name but I did not find something relevant or meaningfull.

This situation occured after lot of crashes and updates of my program on that computer (I am a developer). One day, it suddenly started not to open files. I did not touch registry or did not change something other on OS.

---

My executable's name is karbon_tart.exe
When it start, it calls CreateFile (open mode  if exist or create mode if not exist) to open karbon_tart.log file and karbon_tart.ini file.
With the files are exist and without the file exists, I tried two times and none of them, the program can open the files.
But if I just rename the name to karbon_tart_a.exe, program can open files no matter if they are exist or not.

Thank you for your interest
Regards
Ömür Ölmez.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out at the end.
It is because of an old copy of my application in Virtual Store.